# Extract compiler and linker flags from Bazel

Tags: bazel, compiler-flags, linker-flags, bazel-cpp

I need to extract the compiler flags and linker flags for a certain application that is built by Bazel.

Is there a specific command to do so?

Answer (score 1):

```
bazel clean # force bazel to rebuild everything  
bazel build -s //...
```

There are more advanced approaches, e.g.:

- [kythe](https://kythe.io/examples/#extracting-compilations-using-bazel)
- [Hedron's Compile Commands Extractor for Bazel](https://github.com/hedronvision/bazel-compile-commands-extractor)
- https://github.com/vincent-picaud/Bazel_and_CompileCommands

You can also use system tools such as [strace](https://strace.io/) to figure how what tools are called by Bazel and which command line parameters are involved.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, bazel build -s prints the copts and linkopts on the cmd. But mu usecase to to print them in a file. I tried several trials, however I didn’t get them.