# Query Bazel compilation target for compiler flags

Tags: bazel, bazel-cpp

How can I query Bazel for the compiler flags used to build a C/C++ target?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract compiler and linker flags from Bazel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74644990/extract-compiler-and-linker-flags-from-bazel)

Comment: I want to get the command for a specific target.  Something like `bazel cquery ... //my:target`.